# Secure text entry ORKAnswerFormat in ResearchKit

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, passwords, researchkit

I saw that `ORKEmailAnswerFormat` was recently added to the master branch of ResearchKit to validate e-mails. It would be nice to have a `ORKPasswordAnswerFormat` too, with a `.setSecureTextEntry` property. In the mean time, I've tried to use the `taskViewController:stepViewControllerWillAppear:` delegate method to access the view hierarchy for an `ORKFormStep`, but I can't seem to find any UITextField or anything like it in the view hierarchy. How can I access the `UITextField` for an `ORKFormItem` with a .textAnswerFormat format such that I can enable secure text entry for that textfield?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to do it in the framework.
A new issue has been opened:
 https://github.com/ResearchKit/ResearchKit/issues/352